# PowerShell, Object = Start Process?

Tags: windows, powershell, com, comobject

**Hi I would like to start the Internet Explorer without extensions and control it. (Navigate to other pages, click buttons etc.)**

When I use the command: "Start iexplore.exe -ArgumentList -extoff" I have the IExplore without extensions, but no object. I need the object to navigate to different pages and click buttons.
"$ie = Start iexplore.exe -ArgumentList -extoff" is not possible with the Command "Start X"

The following code create a Com Object and all I want is possible **without the "Extensions = off"**

- $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
- $ie.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
- $ie.Navigate("www.Navigate to a other Page.com")
- $ie.Document.getElementById("ButtonID")|foreach{
- $_.Click()
- }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a real hack but you could tweak the COM startup commandline for IE to pass in the argument `-extoff`.  The registry entry to start IE on my machine (with IE9) is:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32

Note that you might need to override the regkey permissions to edit the value.

Comment: Hey Keith, thank you very much! Can you tell me more about the editing? I found: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetExplorer.Application\CLSID but what must I edit?

Comment: sorry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is my IE

Comment: You edit the default value of the LocalServer32 regkey.  The value is the commandline that starts the IE.exe.  Just append -extoff outside the double quotes e.g. `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -extoff`.  Once again, this is a hack but it might work for you.